# put margin on border - css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put some margin to this border :

[image]

Here is the css code :

```
.select_dev {
    width: 15vmax;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #142431;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    border: 2.5px dashed #babfc5;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}
```

I already tried `border-spacing: 15px`, but this doesn't work.. How can I do it please ?

Here is the HTML Code :

```
<div class="select_dev">
        <div class="drgndrop">
            <div class="textninput">
                <center style="margin-top: 10px;">Faites glisser vos documents ici</center>
                <center style="margin-top: 5px;"><img width="60" height="auto" src="plus2.png"></center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onmouseover="help_hover(0, this)" onmouseout="hide_hover()" id="gear_button" style="background-color: Transparent; border: none; cursor:pointer; transform: translateX(+70px)"><img id="gear" src="UploadInactiv.png" style="width: 39px; height: auto"></button>
        <button style="background-color: Transparent; border: none; cursor:pointer; transform: translateX(+100px)" onclick="delete_files_selected()" onmouseover="help_hover(1, this)" onmouseout="hide_hover()"><img src="delete.png" style="width: 40px; height: auto"></button>
        <div class="acidjs-css3-treeview" style="margin-left: 5px"></div>
    </div>
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: Do you have a live fiddlle? have you tried margin?

Comment: The border-spacing CSS property sets the distance between the borders of adjacent `<table>` cells. Are you styling a table?

Comment: you can use margin or padding, depends on the results you want

Comment: I don't have any table, i'm just trying to have a border but with some margin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Margin` adds 50 px on the outside of the `div`

`Padding` adds 50 px on the inside of the `div`

You can see the results of the margin and padding if you run the code snippet

```css
body{
  background-color: yellow;
}
#margin{
  background-color: green;
  margin: 50px;
}
#padding{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="margin"><h1>This div has margin</h1></div>
  <div id="padding"><h1>This div has padding</h1></div>
</body>
```

For your code it would be something like this

**Margin**

```css
.select_dev {
    width: 15vmax;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #142431;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    border: 2.5px dashed #babfc5;
    border-spacing: 15px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_dev">
        <div class="drgndrop">
            <div class="textninput">
                <center style="margin-top: 10px;">Faites glisser vos documents ici</center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="acidjs-css3-treeview" style="margin-left: 5px"></div>
    </div>
```

**Padding**

```css
.select_dev {
    width: 15vmax;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #142431;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    border: 2.5px dashed #babfc5;
    border-spacing: 15px;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_dev">
        <div class="drgndrop">
            <div class="textninput">
                <center style="margin-top: 10px;">Faites glisser vos documents ici</center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="acidjs-css3-treeview" style="margin-left: 5px"></div>
    </div>
```

I hope my answer was helpful
Try the code and let me know if it helped

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `padding` style to div.

```
      .select_dev {
                width: 15vmax;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #142431;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 200;
                border: 2.5px dashed #babfc5;
                border-spacing: 15px;
                padding:10px;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: I will add it in like 2 minute ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want gap outside border then use `margin` 
if gap inside border use `padding`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.box{
      width: 15vmax;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #142431;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 200;
      border: 2.5px dashed #babfc5;
      border-spacing: 15px;
      padding:10px;
      
      margin:10px; // this is what you need
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: If i put a margin like this, it will move my entire div... and padding, only put the margin inside, for the text ... but not for the border.